# Ordering the styles in the layer window

Tags: qgis

I created display rules for my layer. They appear well ordered in the style window but are not so in the layer window. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: It looks like they are in the correct order to me.

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto The groups are not shown on the layer panel

Comment: See this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421991/group-style-groups-within-on-layer-in-qgis)